# Is there a way to access a shadowed variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
 var a=1;   //first one
 function x() {
    var a=2;  // second
    function y() {
       var a=3;  // third one
    }
 }
```

Is there any way that `function y()` can access the **second** `var a`? I know it can access first one via `window.a`.

Comment: That's my help too: change the name of the second a variable

Comment: @Ed - It is not a stupid question, specially when you do not already know the answer. It is very possible other languages would allow that (for example: `parentClosure.a`)

Comment: @EdHeal: i know it's a simple solution  changing variable name but i want to know this from technical point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As-written?
No.

If you're not dead-set on naming each one `a`, then you can easily reference it.
The other solution would be to capture the outside variable within another variable, the trick being to not have the same variable name being referenced in the outside scope, from the inside scope.

```
window.a = 1;
function x() {
    var a = 2,
        inner_a = a,

        y = function () {
            var old_a = inner_a,
            // a is equal to the closest var assignment ie: inside x()
                a = 3;
        };
 }
```

or to pass it into the construction of a new function through closure
(immediately-invoking function)

```
window.a = 1;
function x() {
    var a = 2;
    var y = (function (old_a) {
        return function () { var a = 3; }; 
        // this inner function has access to "old_a", through closure
    }(a));
}
```

This is a pattern that is preferred for several use-cases, when mixing JS with browser-functionality (ie: the DOM and DOM events, loops which assign timers or callbacks, AJAX responses, et cetera).

Comment: The `old_a = a` technique in your first solution doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/KNLhW/ (variable hoisting declares the inner `a` before the assignment to `old_a`).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Very good point! Here is another fun version: `var old_a = a;` `alert(old_a);` `var a = 3;` - doesn't work either. http://jsfiddle.net/KNLhW/1/

Comment: You're right, @nnnnnn.  I'll fix that.  Normally, all of my functions are, themselves, statements, rather than declarations.  I'll fix that right now.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you declare the function, the variable hoisting effect still takes place inside the function. So your updated code doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/KNLhW/2/

Comment: @nnnnnn - you're correct.  The first one isn't going to work -- I'll fix that.  However, that's not exactly a problem with hoisting, so much as it's a problem with the compiler's scope-resolution, as a side-effect of hoisting: if they were two different variable names, the hoisting would make absolutely 0% difference.  If a temporary outer-variable named `inner_a` were created, it could easily be referenced inside, cached in a temporary variable, and then moved to suit whichever need is required.  Regardless, the sane and predictable answer has always been closure.

Comment: If they were two different variable names there wouldn't be a problem to work around in the first place...

Comment: @nnnnnn Of course.  But like I said in the first statement of my answer, it's a question of him being dead-set upon having actual procedural code in multiple scopes accessing variables with the exact same name in each scope -- if he's not dead-set upon doing so, it's a non-issue.  If he's really 100% set upon having everything share a common variable name, for one reason or another (`that` might be valid in very specific circumstances, though would most-often default to `window` -- `i` might be another), these are ways around such a thing.  The closure obviously being preferred.