# Accessing Shadowed Variable in Self Executing Function

Tags: javascript, function, scope, self-executing-function

In the following example, is there any way to get a reference to the *someValue* variable declared outside *someFunction* from within *someFunction* or is it completely obscured by the function's parameter of the same name. I appreciate that I could attach it to window and access it from within the function using *this*, but is there a way of accessing it in this situation?

[Edit] To clarify. I understand that the parameter is shadowing the variable. Obviously changing the name of the parameter would remove this issue. My question is whether there is any way to access the variable given this situation.

```
(function($){

   var someValue = 41;

   function someFunction(someValue) {

      console.log(someValue); //= 22

   }

   someFunction(22);


}(jQuery));
```

Comment: So in your example, you'd like the `console.log()` to output 41, correct?

Comment: can't you rename the function's param?

Comment: No. It is completely shadowed, and there is no way to get around it. Rename one the two variables.

Comment: once upon a time, there was a `.__parent__` property which could get accessed by ECMAscript. But those are just rumors, because that was a long time ago. Currently, there is no option to directly access parent contexts.

Comment: @BenM Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @AlexMihai No. The point of the question is that *in this situation* is there any way to access the shadowed variable.

Comment: @1ndivisible: Yes, I thought that's what you were asking, I just couldn't think of a situation where you'd be constrained to this. :) I guess your question was more of a theoretical one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access a shadowed variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816700/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-shadowed-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be deliberately shadowing the variable, and then trying to get its value. Just give it a different name or rename your parameter.

```
   var someValue = 41;
   function someFunction(myParameter) {
      console.log(someValue); // someValue == 41
   }
   someFunction(22); // logs 41
```

Comment: I know that's what is happening. My question was whether in this situation I could get access to the shadowed variable.

Comment: @1ndivisible No, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to log the `someValue` that was declared outside the function, unless you're going to pass the variable:

```
(function($){
    var someValue = 41;

    function someFunction(someValue, otherValue) {
        console.log(someValue, otherValue); //= 22 41
    }
    someFunction(22, someValue);
}(jQuery));
```

Or rename the parameter:

```
(function($){
    var someValue = 41;

    function someFunction(otherValue) {
        console.log(someValue); //= 41
    }
    someFunction(someValue);
}(jQuery));
```

This is because the `someValue` name you use as parameter overshadows the one declared outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using local variable (var), the context of someValue is set to the function. The best solution is to use a different name as suggested by others, if you are desperate to use the same name though you could attach it to window object by removing the *var* keyword like so:

```
(function($) {

    someValue = 41;

    function someFunction(someValue) {
        console.log(window.someValue); //= 41
        console.log(someValue); //= 22
    }

    someFunction(22);

}(jQuery));
```