# accessing a variable from parent scope in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var db_server  = "primary";
var that = this;
var startServerWith = function(db_server) {
    try {
        console.log(that.db_server);
        console.log(db_server);
                // start
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Sever failed " , err.message);
    }
};

startServerWith("secondary");
```

Returned :

```
undefined
secondary
```

how can I access the patent var db_server data ("primary").in side the function in (NodeJS)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Shadowed Variable in Self Executing Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761271/accessing-shadowed-variable-in-self-executing-function)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access shadowed variable in javascript (except for special cases like when it's global).

Just don't name two variables the same name if you need to access both of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var main = function() {
    db_server  = "primary";
    var that = this;
    var startServerWith = function(db_server) {
        try {
            console.log(that.db_server);
            console.log(db_server);
                    // start
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Sever failed " , err.message);
        }
    };

    startServerWith("secondary");
}

main();
```

Returns:

```
primary
secondary
```