# How to access let variable outside a block in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope

```js
var x = 10;
{
    let x = 9;
    console.log(x)
}
console.log(x)
```

This logs 9 and 10

how to get a log as 10 and 10?
how to access x declared outside the block?

Comment: There isn't any TypeScript in your question. Read about the [`let` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) in the JavaScript documentation about [declarations and statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Comment: You use blocks to limit the scope of a variable. The main reason of a block is that `x` is not accessible outside the block. If you want to access a variable outside a bock, declare it outside the block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access a shadowed variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816700/is-there-a-way-to-access-a-shadowed-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

No, You can't access `let` variables outside the block, if you really want to access, declare it outside, which is common scope.

```js
let x;
{
    x = 9
    console.log(x)
}
x = 10
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` has block scope so it is scoped only inside the brackets. You can define it outside or use `var` instead of `let` keyword as below:

```js
{
 var x = 10;
 console.log(x)
}
console.log(x)
```

With `let` keyword:

```js
let x = 10;
{
 console.log(x)
}
console.log(x)
```

For detailed explanation about the variable scope refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'var' keyword instead of 'let', it can be accessed globally

```
{
    var x = 10;
    console.log(x)
}
console.log(x)
```

or in your solution you can also declare let outside the block and reassign it inside the block

```
 let x = 10;
 {
    x = 9
    console.log(x)
 }
 console.log(x)
```